# how to make my app work in BB devices without SD card

Tags: blackberry

I have an app. When I am loading the cod files in BB device, the app gets loaded perfectly, but when I am trying to open the app from the device, it is showing me this error.

"Error in initializing Database. Please insert a SD card and try again".

SD card is already in the device but I want to run my app WITHOUT THE SD CARD.

Comment: your app is unable to find the SDCard path for storing database file..check what path you are giving.

Comment: your code is trying to access the sd card. thats the error.Or check the proper location of that database location

Comment: probably using a copy-pasta database interface with the path set to `file:///SDCard/`. You can change that to be `file:///store/`

Comment: I want to run the app in a device, which doesn't have SD card. how can i do that?

Comment: @Doel, you need to post the code from your app that's trying to use the SDCard for something (I assume there is code attempting to read/write from the SDCard).

Answer (score 2):

To store database use internal device storage instead of SDCard.

Check [this article](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_files_in_the_file_system_1219757_11.jsp) about internal and sdcard storage.

And [this article](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_data_in_SQLite_databases_1219769_11.jsp) about working with SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

I think  there is two thing first you are putting your data base on SDCard .You just change the path database .Change to file:///store/.
2) I also getting same error when there is no network in device .I open the network it works fine for me.
Do both the process  and check